# Adding columns to CSV with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to sort a CSV file.

I read the data from the file and store it into a hash:

```
somecsv = 'somecsv.csv'
CSV_Hash = {}
CSV.foreach(somecsv) do |col1, col2, col3|
    CSV_Hash[col1] = col2, col3
end
```

I then do some sorting and want to write the data back into a CSV file:

```
CSV.open('somecsv2.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    CSV_Hash.each do |row|
        csv << row
    end
end
```

The sample data is:

```
Filename      REG1     REG2
zFile.exe     A        E
bFile.exe     B        F
aFile.exe     C        G
```

My expected output is:

```
Filename      REG1     REG2
aFile.exe     C        G
bFile.exe     B        F
zFile.exe     A        E
```

The actual output is:

```
Filename      ["REG1, REG2"]
aFile.exe     ["C, G"]
bFile.exe     ["B, F"]
zFile.exe     ["A, E"]
```

My code works perfectly when I just had two columns, and I understand why it doesn't work for the third column. I just don't know where else to look to separate out the third column.

If this helps, this is what the hash looks like when output to the console:

```
{"Filename"=>["REG1", "REG2"], "aFile.exe"=>["C", "G"], "bFile.exe"=>["B", "F"], "zFile.exe"=>["A", "E"]}
```

Comment: How about an additional `row.each do |data|`

Comment: You don't say what OS you're on, but typically I'd sort a CSV file using the built-in `sort` command on Linux. Its `-t` (for field separator) and `-k` (for start/stop sort column) parameters make it possible to identify and sort on a particular column. You can tell it to use numeric sorting order if you want also. It's a LOT faster and can handle huge files. The only time I've run into problems is when a field contains the field-separator.

Comment: The OS is Windows 7, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV writer expects a flattened array, not the tuple `string => array`:

```
- csv << row
+ csv << row.flatten
```

Hope it helps.